# Как объединить несколько input в одну строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок в Python, и мне нужен наиболее "питонский" способ объединить несколько инпутов в одну строку на примере данного кода, через пробел вывести 3 значения одной строкой, и в конце получить результат. Как это можно лучше всего сделать в Python? Не хочу выводить по одному инпуту на строку. Буду благодарен за помощь.

**Код:**

```
def main():
    floated = float_input('\n' + "Введите сумму: ")
    conversion2 = conversion_func2('\n' + "Введите изначальную валюту: ")
    conversion = conversion_func('\n' + "В какую валюту перевести?: ")
    while True:
        if conversion == conversion2:
            print('Ошибка! Нельзя конвертировать в изначальную валюту!')
            conversion = conversion_func('\n' + "В какую валюту перевести?: ")
        else:
            print('\n' + 'Результат: ' + str(floated*conversion2/conversion))
            break



while True:
    main()
```

Comment: Вы это хотите: `x, y, z = input().split()`?

Comment: Думаю, да :) Не покажете как это можно сделать на примере моего кода? Проблема в том что у меня функции по сути и есть input'ы, ведь они принимают текст. В таком случае, как эти input'ы можно склеить? Спасибо заранее!

Comment: На примере Вашего кода так не получится, функции не склеятся. Мне вот что кажется, либо сначала соберите все данные, а потом передавайте функциям, либо оставьте как есть. Не вижу больших проблем в том, что каждый `input` будет на отдельной строке.

Comment: Не стоит делать строки, начинающиеся переводом строки. Это символ имеет специальную магию, которую вы таким образом обрубаете почти на корню.

Answer (score 1):

```
Delimeter = ";"
floated, conversion2, conversion = input(": ").split(Delimeter)
```

Разделит строку по конкретному знаку.

PS
"\n" Можно сразу в строке писать, а не складывать их:

```
"\nВ какую валюту перевести?: "
```

Answer (score 0):

Я, конечно, не профессионал в Python, но мне кажется правильней будет этот код:

```
def main():
floated = float(input('\n' + "Введите сумму: "))
conversion2 = float(input('\n' + "Введите изначальную валюту: "))
conversion = float(input('\n' + "В какую валюту перевести?: "))
while True:
    if conversion == conversion2:
        print('Ошибка! Нельзя конвертировать в изначальную валюту!')
        conversion = float(input('\n' + "В какую валюту перевести?: "))
    else:
        print('\n' + 'Результат: ' + str(floated*conversion2/conversion))
        break



while True:
    main()
```